# Poisson Process Conditional Probability Question

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes

I was hoping to get verification that I am on the right track and doing/ thinking about the following problem correctly:

Customers arrive at a service facility according to a Poisson process of rate $\lambda$ = 5 per hour. Given that 12 customers arrived during the first two hours of service, what is the conditional probability that 5 customers arrived during the first hour?

This is what I have so far:

Let X(t) = the number of customers arrived up to time t. Fix the times such that 0 < s < t. Then I wanted to use the conditional probability formula Pr{X(t)=n+k|X(s)=n}. So based on my understanding of this question, I have done Pr{X(2)=12|X(1)=5}, so s=1, t=2, n=5 and k=7. 
Solving this, I get Pr{X(1)=7}, so for a Poisson process with rate $\lambda$=5, this is $\frac{{e^{-35}}5^7}{7!}$ = 15.5$e^{-35}$

Is this correct?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

We can **mechanically** use the defining formula for conditional probability. As an exercise, we will go through the process. But the ultimate result is so simple that it invites further thinking.

Let $B$ be the event there were $12$ in the first two hours, and let $A$ be the event there were $5$ in the first hour. We want $\Pr(A|B)$. This is $\frac{\Pr(A\cap B)}{\Pr(B)}$.

Calculate. The number of arrivals in $2$ hours is Poisson with parameter $10$, so $\Pr(B)=e^{-10}\frac{10^{12}}{12!}$.

For the event $A\cap B$, note this happens if there are $5$ in the first and $7$ in the second. This has probability $\left(e^{-5}\frac{5^{5}}{5!}\right)\left( e^{-5}\frac{5^{7}}{7!}\right)$.

Divide. The powers of $e$ stuff cancels, and we end up with something that may be very familiar to you from your experience with the binomial distribution. With some manipulation, we arrive at
$$\binom{12}{5}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{12}.$$

**Added:** Such a simple answer deserves a simple explanation. We had $12$ occurrences of a customer arriving. Label these $12$ customers in an arbitrary random way. Call a customer **prompt** if she arrives in the first hour. The probability that a customer randomly chosen from the $12$ is prompt is $\frac{1}{2}$, since she is equally likely to have arrived in the first hour as in the second. So the probability that exactly $5$ of the $12$ customers are prompt is $\binom{12}{5}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{12}$.

**Remarks:** $1.$ You should track down the general case. We have a Poisson with rate $\lambda$ (per hour). Given that there were $n$ arrivals in the first $a+b$ hours, what is the probability that there are  $k$ arivals in the first $a$ hours? Go through the same conditional probability calculation. You will get a familiar "binomial-type" expression. Now explain why the result is "obvious," and the conditional probability machinery  was not necessary.

$2.$ Given that there were $12$ successes in $2$ hours, the event that there were $5$ in the first hour sounds not unlikely. So the number obtained in the post is too small by several orders of magnitude.

Comment: Wow, thank you for such a detailed response! I see that I had my conditional probability set up wrong originally (I had them flipped) and that I had calculated Pr(B) wrong.

Comment: You are welcome. I have added explanation in the post for "why" the final answer is so simple.

Comment: Why is it the case that $$Pr(A\cap B) = \left(e^{-5}\frac{5^{5}}{5!}\right)\left( e^{-5}\frac{5^{7}}{7!}\right)$$

Comment: yep @sam good question. I also don't see that.

Comment: @sam because they are independent