# simple poisson application

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, poisson-distribution

[image]

[image]

I am trying to solve a previous exam question for one of my courses, but there are no solutions.I've tried to somehow link this to the uniform distribution since we know exactly how many tourists arrive, but I can't get an answer - could someone please provide a solution. Thanks

Comment: I have the solution, they calculate that the probability of 1 visitor in the first ten minutes is 1/6 - I don't see how, I can use the poisson distribution to get it but it's not 1/6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A$ be the event exactly one arrived in the first $10$ minutes, and $B$ the event $20$ arrived in the first hour. We want $\Pr(A\mid B)$, which is $\Pr(A\cap B)/\Pr(B)$.

Easily, $\Pr(B)=e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^{20}}{20!}$.

To calculate $\Pr(A\cap B)$, multiply $\Pr(A)$ by the probability $19$ people arrived in the next $5/6$ of an hour. We have
$$\Pr(A)=e^{-\lambda/6}\frac{(\lambda/6)^1}{1!},$$
and the probability of $19$ arrivals in the next $5/6$ of an hour is
$$e^{-5\lambda/6}\frac{(5\lambda/6)^{19}}{19!}.$$
Multiply. We get $e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^{20}(1/6)(5/6)^{19}}{19!}$.

Divide by $\Pr(B)$. There is a fair bit of cancellation, and we end up with $20(1/6)(5/6)^{19}$.

*Remark*: Note that our probability has a familiar "binomial distribution" shape.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, my original thinking was, if $20$ arrive in an hour, we have the rate $\lambda$ as $1/3$ so in 10 minutes, we have tourists arriving at a rate of $10/3$, so I caculated the probability of 1 arriving using the possion distribution. If this gave me $1/6$ I would be done after using the binomial - could you tell me what's wrong with this approach?

Comment: Knowing that $20$ arrived in an hour does not tell us the rate, though it likely gives a reasonably good approximation to the rate. It is by the way a standard result that the conditional distribution of the number of arrivals in the first $s$ hours, given that there were $N$ arrivals in the first $s+t$ hours, is binomial. Basically the same calculation as in our specific example.

Comment: alright, thanks again!

Comment: sorry just to ask another question - in the solutions it states exactly $\binom{20}{1} (1/6)(5/6)^{19}$ which leads me to believe that they must have figured out the $1/6$ beforehand, then used the binomail theorem (this is how we've approached these types of questions before. Do you have any insight onto how we can calculate the $1/6$? I thought it might be "the probability that 1 customer arrives in 10 minutes$, but my attempt to find that was above

Comment: You are welcome.   And of course the answer is not $1/6$. Whatever reasoning led to $1/6$ would presumably work if there were $3000$ arrivals in the first hour, and then the probability of only $1$ arrival in the first $10$ minutes would be very tiny. It is true that the number of arrivals in rhe first $10$ minutes has (unconditional) Poisson distribution with parameter $\lambda/6$.

Comment: In a Poisson process with rate $\lambda$ (per hour say), the number of events in an interval of time of length $t$ has Poisson distribution with rate $\lambda t$. We used that twice in the calculation, first for $\Pr(A)$, and then for the probability of $19$ arrivals in the time interval of length $5/6$.

Comment: I follow that, but I am just worrying that perhaps there might be a simpler way, because if we did figure out the probability $p$ of 1 arriving in 10 minutes, then the answer would be exactly $\binom{20}{1} p (1-p)^{19}$ but that's all I have from the solutions - it just doesn't seem like they did it your exact method though (which I do follow)

Comment: I used the standard method. Of course one can quote the general result, the conditional distribution of the number of arrivals in the first $1/6$ of a period is binomial parameters $n=20$, $p=1/6$. The usual proof is essentially the same as the one I gave.  But one can also derive the result without computation, from the axioms that characterize a Poisson process,

Comment: so what I'm asking really is, why is it clearly a binomial distribution? if you see here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/328230/poisson-process-conditional-probability-question the answer states the result is obvious - I just can't see how

Comment: Because of the homogeneity of a Poisson process with constant rate, the   probability that any particular one of the $n$ arrivals in time $T$ arrived in a particular subperiod of length $t$ is $t/T$. Now apply this to $n$ arrivals. Under the natural independence assumption, we get the binomial. However, this intuitive description is reached a little later than the computational approach. Indeed it becomes obvious after a while, but I think not immediately.